# Create list of lists from Groupedby dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, pandas-groupby

Assume my df is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Order ID': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'Product': ['USB', 'Bat', 'Ball', 'USB', 'Phone', 'Toy', 'Bike', 'Apple']})
```

I want to group by Order ID, and then put the Product values in a list of lists depending on the frequency of their Order ID.  For example -

```
[['USB', 'Bat'], ['Ball'], ['USB', 'Phone', 'Toy'], ['Bike', 'Apple']]
```

USB and Bat both have the same order ID (1), so they are in the same list.

My code, trial 1:

```
combo_outer = []  # outer most list

grouped = df.groupby(['Order ID', 'Product'])

for group, frame in grouped:
    
    combo_inner = []    # for inner lists

    for row_index, row in frame.iterrows():
    
        combo_inner.append(row['Product'])
    
    combo_outer.extend(combo_inner)
```

Trial 2:

```
df['Product'].values.tolist()
```

In both cases, I end up getting a single list:

```
['Bat', 'USB', 'Ball', 'Phone', 'Toy', 'USB', 'Apple', 'Bike']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Trial 1, instead of using `extend`, you should use `append`. Or you can use list comprehension:

```
[g.values.tolist() for _, g in df.Product.groupby(df['Order ID'])]
# [['USB', 'Bat'], ['Ball'], ['USB', 'Phone', 'Toy'], ['Bike', 'Apple']]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first trial just do this: `grouped = df.groupby(['Order ID'])` instead of `grouped = df.groupby(['Order ID', 'Product'])`

The second thing is, use `append` in the last line instead of `extend`

Trail one should be something like this:

```
combo_outer = []  # outer most list

grouped = df.groupby(['Order ID'])

for group, frame in grouped:
    
    combo_inner = []    # for inner lists

    for row_index, row in frame.iterrows():
    
        combo_inner.append(row['Product'])
    
    combo_outer.append(combo_inner)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send the list function directly to the groupby using `agg` and convert to a list.

```
df.Product.groupby(df['Order ID']).agg(list).tolist()
```

Outputs:

`[['USB', 'Bat'], ['Ball'], ['USB', 'Phone', 'Toy'], ['Bike', 'Apple']]`

Answer (score 1):

In Trial 1, instead of using **extend**, you should use **append**. Or you can use **apply** function as shown below

```
df1['new']=df.groupby('Order ID')['Product'].apply(list)
df1['new'].values.tolist()
```

OUTPUT

```
[['USB', 'Bat'], ['Ball'], ['USB', 'Phone', 'Toy'], ['Bike', 'Apple']]
```